# Which is better: mysql_connect or mysql_pconnect

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a PHP newbie working a some scripts to display some news articles from a databse and wanted to find out a couple of things.

- For opening a connection to a MySQL database, which is a better option `mysql_connect` or `mysql_pconnect`?
- What are the advantages or drawbacks of using a persistent connection to the database?
- And in what kind of scenario will a persistent connection be called for?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247807/mysqlconnect-vs-mysqlpconnect

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are going to write a web page there is no need of persistent connection. It takes too much resources. Use mysql_connect. Minimize the time your db connection is open and not used as much as you can. Open, fetch what you want, close. It doesn't need to stay open while the users are just reading. The connection will be used eventually if they respond - INSERT/go to another page..

[Here](http://bg.php.net/function.mysql-pconnect#85670) are some good points about **NOT USING** persistent connection in web applications

> - When you lock a table, normally it is unlocked when the connection closes, but since persistent connections do not close, any tables you
>     accidentally leave locked will remain locked, and the only way to
>     unlock them is to wait for the connection to timeout or kill the
>     process. The same locking problem occurs with transactions. (See
>     comments below on 23-Apr-2002 & 12-Jul-2003)
> - Normally temporary tables are dropped when the connection closes, but since persistent connections do not close, temporary tables aren't
>     so temporary. If you do not explicitly drop temporary tables when you
>     are done, that table will already exist for a new client reusing the
>     same connection. The same problem occurs with setting session
>     variables. (See comments below on 19-Nov-2004 & 07-Aug-2006)
> - If PHP and MySQL are on the same server or local network, the connection time may be negligible, in which case there is no advantage
>     to persistent connections.
> - Apache does not work well with persistent connections. When it receives a request from a new client, instead of using one of the
>     available children which already has a persistent connection open, it
>     tends to spawn a new child, which must then open a new database
>     connection. This causes excess processes which are just sleeping,
>     wasting resources, and causing errors when you reach your maximum
>     connections, plus it defeats any benefit of persistent connections.
>     (See comments below on 03-Feb-2004, and the footnote at
>     http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/686#fn1)

Comment: The reason you usually use mysql_pconnect is exactly when you're making a web application so you don't have to do the expensive operation of connecting to the database for every page rendered.

Comment: and why should my connection stay open while I'm reading my horoscope for examle, it may take 1 hour after I ask for another page?!

Comment: i've seen this post somewhere before... looks copy pasted. Anyhow, this topic has been explored before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128329/mysql-persistent-connections-and-advantages-of-mysqlpconnect

Comment: You should probably cite the source of those points: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php#85670. Using mysql_pconnect is more of a burden in terms of more quickly reaching the connection limit and having to manage that, than actual resource consumption.

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at [mysqli](http://nl.php.net/mysqli) and [pdo](http://nl.php.net/pdo). mysql-extension is pretty old and does not support prepared statements mysqli does. And pdo supports multiple databases without changing queries.

Answer (score 1):

You should use mysql_pconnect on highly loaded sites, thus the connection would be reused. This may improve speed up to twice...

But, if you do not expect high loads; use normal connect for reasons Svetlozar Angelov mentioned above.